# How to place text over table border in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

I want to repeat same table, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your table.

Insert a text box on the page. Inside it, type the text you want to be placed over the border. Resize the text box to correctly fit your text.

Then select the text box by clicking on its border.

Go to Shape Format Tab in the ribbon (possibly named just *Format* in previous versions of Word). There, find the Wrap Text button. From the options inside it, select *In Front of Text*.

Now when you reposition the text box, it will overlap with the table border.

Once you have positioned the text box in the right place, go the format tab again and set Shape Outline to none. This should make it look like the image you have supplied.

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLOqo.png)